# Parser.Default.ParseArguments always returns false

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have added CommandLineParser library into my project and I have configure all the arguments which should be provided to my project for to support silent installation of the same.

An InstallOptions class is being created with some "Option" attributes for each of the required and non-required arguments to the same e.g. below

```
public class InstallOptions
{
    [Option("path", Required = true, HelpText = "The installation path where you want the application installed.")]
    public string InstallPath { get; set; }

    [Option("dbname", Required = true, HelpText = "Database name.")]
    public string DbName { get; set; }

    [Option("dbserver", Required = true, HelpText = "Database server name or IP address.")]
    public string DbServer { get; set; }

    [HelpOption]
    public string DisplayHelpOnParseError()
    {
        var help = new HelpText()
        {
            AddDashesToOption = true
        };
        var errors = "";

        if (LastParserState.Errors.Any())
        {
            errors = help.RenderParsingErrorsText(this, 0);
        }

        //HACK fix where if help.addoptions is called more than once it truncates the output
        if (_help == null)
        {
            help.AddOptions(this);
            _help = help;
        }
        else
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(errors) ? _help : "ERROR(S):" + errors + _help;
        }

        return help;
    }
}
```

From my program.cs file I want to debug I am running my project as below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        args = new string[3];
        args[0] = "--path C:\\Program files\MyProject";
        args[1] = "--dbname myDBName";
        args[2] = "--dbserver myDBServer";

        var result = Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, installOptions);
        if (!result) throw new ArgumentException(installOptions.DisplayHelpOnParseError());
    }
```

in the above code I all the time getting result = false and states throws below error message

--path required. The installation path where you want the application installed.

--dbname required. Database name.

--dbserver required. Database server name or IP address.

Please help me how to pass all 3 parameter to my project to test it is working correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which CommandLineParser library (there are many)?

Comment: CommandLineParser.1.9.71.dll library

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/1.9.71   this one

Answer (score 2):

Arguments should be passed as below

[image: arguments]